# no puedo hacer foco a mi input después de que lo lleno con ajax

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Así lleno con ajax mi input contraseña:

```
$('#divClave').html("<input name="txtPasswordCliente" type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPasswordCliente" placeholder="Password">");
```

Aquí le quiero dar el foco, pero no lo hace, sólo pone el input vacío:

```
$('input[name=txtPasswordCliente]').val("");
$("#txtPasswordCliente").focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

bienvenido a SO! El foco funciona, pero tu primera linea tiene un error: usas comillas dobles dentro de un bloque con comillas dobles. Una vez corregido eso, todo lo demás empieza a funcionar.

```js
$('#divClave').html('<input name="txtPasswordCliente" type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPasswordCliente" placeholder="Password">');

$('input[name=txtPasswordCliente]').val("");
$("#txtPasswordCliente").focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="lalla" value="enfocar primero">
<div id="divClave"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirma que estas haciendo focus después de haber insertando el input ya que de lo contrario no lo encontrara.

Aquí un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$('#divClave').html('<input name="txtPasswordCliente" type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPasswordCliente" placeholder="Password">');

$('input[name=txtPasswordCliente]').val("").focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divClave"></div>
```

Comment: si, primero inserto el input en mi divclave con ajax, y todo normal, el problema es cuando quiero poner el foco en mi input